# Token units in whole number

Tags: token

I have a requirement of custom token to be in whole number only.
For example, let the limit of token be 100 then it can be trade / transfer in terms of whole number like 1,2 ..etc.
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to build a custom wallet/interface for those tokens, you could interpret 0.0000001 as 1 unit. In that case you get indivisible tokens. Nevertheless, all other wallets will show fractions in balances that might be confusing for users.

Comment: My requirement is to create anchor for assets such as stocks. Whole number is an important requirement. If I use 0.0000001 unit as 1 unit, internally it might work but orderbook will confuse.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no support for indivisible units in Stellar.